# mysql INSERT IF NOT EXISTS practical sample

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying the whole day but without any luck. I want to write a MySQL Routine (Query) to populate one table with data from another table.
Both tables have unique, not null & primary key (column name) and both tables have (column code).
How to copy data from one table to another, without updating existing data? I want to ignore rows existing in both tables.

export   (name PK)

| no | name | value | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mercy | 100 | 119001 |
| 2 | Oreo | 50 | 232221 |
| 3 | Jelly | 70 | 331000 |
| 4 | Solar | 55 | 411411 |
| ---- | ------ | ------- | ------- |

tb_code (name PK)

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| Solar | 411411 |
| ------ | ------- |

```
INSERT INTO tb_code (name, code) FROM export (SELECT name, code) WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

Result should be

tb_code (name PK)

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| Solar | 411411 |
| Mercy | 119001 |
| Oreo | 232221 |
| Jelly | 331000 |
| ------ | ------- |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is way off...

It's `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM ...` not `INSERT ... FROM ...` (without `SELECT`), that `FROM`-less `SELECT` subquery after `export` is completely misplaced and the `EXISTS` operator needs a subquery as operand -- the set that is checked for its existence (i.e. non-emptiness).

Try:

```
INSERT INTO tb_code
            (name,
             code)
            SELECT e.name,
                   e.code
                   FROM export e
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM tb_code c
                                            WHERE c.name = e.name);
```

You generally had the right ideas but probably should invest more time studying the documentation for the right syntax.

Comment: just `INSERT IGNORE` may do everything they need, too

Comment: This answer is working great. @ysth I know for INSERT IGNORE and I have tried that approach also. For some reason, I couldn't find the appropriate syntax which works for me.